# SCCM - Surefire way of detecting when computer is fully done installing via it's task sequence

Tags: powershell, sccm

I would like your opinion on this. I'm making a simple script for myself to alert me when SCCM is done installing a computer.

I thought : What is a good way of detecting when the installation is truly over?

My reasoning led me to check via a Powershell loop the presence of the very last string in :

"C:\Windows\CCM\Logs\smsts.log"

Which is for example :

```
<![LOG[Successfully finalized logs to SMS client log directory from C:\WINDOWS\CCM\Logs]LOG]!><time="11:47:56.899+240" date="08-17-2018" component="OSDSetupHook" context="" type="1" thread="5644" file="tslogging.cpp:1911">
```

If the pattern "Successfully finalized logs" is found in that file, i'm alerted the installation is done and I can then proceed to run other commands on that computer.

That solution works fine but my question is would you recommend any other surefire way to determine when the task sequence is completely done and the computer is operational? What would you use to detect that?

Thanks a lot for your input.

Comment: This post may help you get to your answer: 

http://www.scconfigmgr.com/2014/04/29/use-powershell-to-determine-if-a-task-sequence-has-successfully-completed/

Comment: Thanks, didn't find that one while searching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@thom schumacher found a link with all the information needed:

http://www.scconfigmgr.com/2014/04/29/use-powershell-to-determine-if-a-task-sequence-has-successfully-completed/